# EntityFramework Many-to-Many serilization cycle

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, many-to-many, .net-5, blazor-webassembly

I have a code first Blazor WebAssembly application in which I have a Many-to-Many relationship.

```
public class A
{
    public A()
    {
        this.Bs = new HashSet<B>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public B()
    {
        this.As= new HashSet<A>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<A> As { get; set; }
}
```

In my client, I call the Get method of the server AController. I would like to have in each A object, the Bs ICollection.

If the Get method is like this, the Bs collection is null :

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<A> Get()
{
    return _context.A.ToList();
}
```

If it is like this, to inlude Bs, I have an exception ("*System.Text.Json.JsonException: A possible object cycle was detected. This can either be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum allowed depth of 32. Consider using ReferenceHandler.Preserve on JsonSerializerOptions to support cycles.*")

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<A> Get()
{
    return _context.A.Include(a => a.Bs).ToList();
}
```

So in my Startup.cs (on the server) I had the following in the ConfigureServices method

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o =>
    o.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve);
```

So now, the serialization works, but the deserialization fails because the JSON is different, not only a List of A.
In the client, I call the get method of the AController like this :

```
 var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync("my_api_adresse");
 return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<List<A>>();
```

But du to the *ReferenceHandler.Preserve* the JSON is like this, so the desirialization can't work and raises an exception :

```
{
"$id": "1",
"$values": [
    {
        "$id": "2",
        "id": 4,
        "name": "nameA3",
        "Bs": {
            "$id": "3",
            "$values": [
                {
                    "$id": "4",
                    "id": 1,
                    "Name": "NameB1",
                    "As": {
                        "$id": "5",
                        "$values": [
                            {
                                "$ref": "2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
}
```

What could I do to be able to include Bs collection into A objects and be able to serialize and deserialize the response without any trouble ?

Answer (score 1):

Try using DTO objects (data transfer objects).
There are many ways. One is:

Create two new classes that are similar to class A and class B, but this one without a list of A objects. Instead, use a list of A Ids. That would solve your problem.
Comment gere if you need code sample